# if - else - Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

Input file "temp.txt" has multiple lines. Script will parse temp.txt and search for these strings on different folders. If result is "True", don't check other folders and continue with next object. Is there any way to accomplish this?

**temp.txt**

```
abc
abd
abe
abf
abg
```

**xyz**

```
m1
m2
m3
m4
m5
```

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile="/home/admin/temp.txt"
xyz=$(echo /home/admin/m*)

function do_job() {
    if [ "$a" -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "$i" 'True';
    else
            echo "$i" 'false';
    fi
}     


for x in ${xyz};
    do
    cd "$x" ||  exit
    while read -r i; do 
    do_job "$i" &
    done < "$tmpfile"
done
```

Comment: Unbalanced quotes in te `if`.  Also missing a `done`.  Also, beware [`command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) is a shell command.

Comment: I typed "command" as an example

Comment: Better `... while read -r i; do do_command "$i"; done < "temp.txt"` (that is a *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use of* `cat`) unless you intended to word-split filenames that contain whitespace)

Comment: It's sorta OK to use `command` as an example, but just like `test`, it is a name that is better avoided.  I'm also not sure what the parentheses in `for x in (xyz)` are supposed to do.  Since it is Bash, maybe you had `for x in $(<xyz)` in mind, though using `while read x; do …; done < xyz` might be better (it would read lines instead of just words).

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Fixed the script. This is some part of the original script. I am running some commands and redirect the output to $a

Comment: Your rewrite is an improvement, but there are still problems. It would be better to use `for x in /home/admin/m*` to get the names. Alternatively, use an array to hold the values: `xyz=( /home/admin/m* )` (the spaces are not crucial) followed by `for x in "${xyz[@]}"` to step through the list. These preserve spaces etc in the names. You can only use `return` in a function; the `for` loop is not in a function. If you use `cd`, I recommend using a sub-shell — it avoids problems with getting back to where you started. It isn't clear what your `read` loop is reading — missed redirection?

Comment: You are right. Redirection was missing. Fixed it.

Comment: The added redirection makes sense.  The `return` is still wrong.  Run from the command line, I get the error ```-bash: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script```.  You might use `continue`, or `break`, or `exit` sensibly.  Consider: `(cd "$x" || exit; while read -r i; do do_job "$i" &; done < "$tmpfile")` as the body of the `for` loop, where the variable `tmpfile` contains the absolute pathname for the file `temp.txt`  — for example, `tmpfile="$PWD/temp.txt"` set before the loop starts — unless each directory you switch to has its own `temp.txt` file.

Comment: I have all these variables on my original script. Since you are seeing part of it, you are right. Adding them here.